Parallax Effect in SwiftUI
I'm trying to reproduce Apple's parallax effect code from their WWDC24 video here but it isn't quite working well.
I have the following code:
struct AnimalView: View {
    let imageName: String
    var body: some View {
        Image(imageName)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 300, height: 450)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 32))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    private let animals = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyHStack(spacing: 16) {
                ForEach(animals, id: \.self) { name in
                    AnimalView(imageName: name)
                        .scrollTransition(.interactive, axis: .horizontal) { content, phase in
                            content.offset(x: phase.value * -250)
                        }
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 32))
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .contentMargins(.horizontal, 32)
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
    }
}


The parallax effect is somewhat there but is jarring and not smooth at all as in Apple's video. I understand the video doesn't show the entire code but it seems to me that the AnimalView needs additional offset to be applied for the transitions to be smoother but I can't quite nail it down. Any help is appreciated.

Took a while. Hope this helps.
struct paging: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let width = geometry.size.width

            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHStack(spacing: 22) {
                    ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { index in
                        ZStack {
                            Image(((index % 2) != 0) ? .t : .h)
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: width, height: 450)                                    .scrollTransition(
                                    axis: .horizontal
                                ) { content, phase in
                                    content.offset(x: phase.value * -(width/2))
                            }
                        }
                         .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                         .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 32))
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .contentMargins(.horizontal, 44)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
        }
    }
}


First, remove the clipShape from AnimalView:
struct AnimalView: View {
    let imageName: String
    var body: some View {
        Image(imageName)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: 300, height: 450)
    }
}

You only need the clipShape after the scrollTransition. The image should be clipped after the scroll transition is applied, not before.
Second, decrease the x offset. -150 looks good to me:
.scrollTransition(.interactive, axis: .horizontal) { content, phase in
    content.offset(x: phase.value * -150)
}

Use an even smaller offset for a weaker parallax effect.
